# Есть post запрос с файлом нужно сохранить файл на C

Tags: c, файлы, post

Сейчас получаются параметры из запроса так:

```
#define ToHex(Y) (Y>='0'&&Y<='9'?Y-'0':Y-'A'+10)

char* InputData;

/** Достает строку с параметрами и ключами из POST или GET запросов */
void getAllParams() {
  // Determing if it is a POST or GET method
  if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")==0) {
    printf("No REQUEST_METHOD, must be running in DOS mode");
    return;
  } else if (strcmp(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"), "POST")==0) {
    // If POST
    char *endptr;   // quite useless, but required
    char *len1 = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    int contentlength = strtol(len1, &endptr, 10);
    InputData = malloc(contentlength*2*sizeof(char));
    fread(InputData , contentlength, 1, stdin);
  } else {
    // If GET
    strcpy(InputData, getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
  }
}

/** Достает параметр из строки по ключу 'Name' и ложет его в 'Value' */
void getParam(const char *Name, char *Value) {
  char *pos1 = strstr(InputData, Name);

  if (pos1) {
    pos1 += strlen(Name);

    if (*pos1 == '=') {
      pos1++;

      while (*pos1 && *pos1 != '&') {
        if (*pos1 == '%') {
          *Value++ = (char)ToHex(pos1[1]) * 16 + ToHex(pos1[2]);
          pos1 += 3;
        } else if(*pos1=='+') {
          *Value++ = ' ';
          pos1++;
        } else {
          *Value++ = *pos1++;
        }
      }
      *Value++ = '\0';
      return;
    }
  }
  strcpy(Value, "undefine");
  return;
}
```

А записываю так:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  getAllParams();
  char* img = malloc(strlen(InputData)*sizeof(char));
  getParam("image", img);
  FILE* f = fopen("img.png", "wb");
  while (*img) {
    fputc((int)*img, f);
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Но естественно запись не работает. Как будет правильно считывать файлы?
В форме стоит атрибут: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (*img) {
    fputc((int)*img, f);
  }
```

Что этот код должен делать? Какая-то бессмысленная конструкция: "пока первый байт массива `img` не равен 0 - записывать его в файл".

Видимо, функция `getParam()` должна возвращать ещё и длину полученного параметра, и тогда код мог бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
size_t sz = getParam("image", img);
/* ... */
fwrite(img, sz, 1, f);
```

(хоть и это тоже кривовато - выделение памяти для `img` лучше делать внутри `getParam()`, но хоть верно с точки зрения логики и языка C)

Вот это, кстати, тоже грубая ошибка:

```
char* img = malloc(strlen(InputData)*sizeof(char));
```

Если у вас `multipart/form-data`, то внутри `InputData` запросто может встретиться нулевой байт.

P.S. Мораль: не надо изобретать велосипедов, для C есть библиотеки, работающие с CGI.

Comment: Можете порекомендовать библиотеку? И запись я знаю что не праивльно сделал. Я хотел посимвольно записывать. Нужно було там добавить `*img++;`

Comment: @Rodion Совсем простые, но вполне рабочие: 1) https://sourceforge.net/projects/libccgi/ 2) https://www.boutell.com/cgic/